# MacOS: Change animation speed of Stage Manager

Tags: macos, mac, window-manager, stage-manager

I'm interested in using Stage Manager for MacOS, but I find the window switching animations too slow.

Is there a way to change the animation speed, e.g. via a Terminal command to alter a .plist setting?

NB: I believe changing window management animation speeds were possible in older versions of OSX; not sure how it works today in general or with Stage Manager.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on the "Reduce motion" setting under Accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!  It's helpful if you give some more context as to *where* Accessibility is located.  Even better would be a simple screen shot showing the location and setting.

Comment: this works for me, I think any macos user would be capable of finding this, but for those who aren't, it's in System Settings > Accessibility  > Display > Reduce motion.. even better for me would be a way to increase the speed but keeping the animations, but maybe that's not possible.